# CXXABI_1.3.8 not found

Tags: games, gcc, c++

So, I'm trying to run heroes of newerth and get the error

```
./hon-x86_64: /home/c0ding/HoN/libs-x86_64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52)
```

From research, I saw to just do `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.2/libstdc++.so` Which didn't seem to do anything. I have several gcc subfolders as well.

Whenever I type gcc it says `gcc: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated`. however I think that's because I didn't point to something to compile. Here's an image: 
[image]

How should I fix this? There's a libstdc++.so but it doesn't have a .6 after it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ && sudo ldconfig && ./hon-x86_64`.

The libstdc++.so file in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.2 is not the one that should be used. Also, a file is being specified (libstdc++.so). You should be specifying the directory the file is in (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/).

You may want to permanently append that path to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable by putting `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` in one of your startup files (~/.bashrc or ~/.profile for example).

Comment: The first line gave an error: warning: The VAD has been replaced by a hack pending a complete rewrite
K2 - Fatal Error: PNG header and library versions do not match

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The previous specified command overwrites the variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH with the path "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu".  I've updated my answer to just append it.  You should probably close and reopen the shell you ran the command in, to get your LD_LIBRARY_PATH back before running the new command.

Comment: ./hon-x86_64 no such file?

Comment: The error PNG header and library versions do not match means that the version of the PNG library (libpng) being used is incorrect.  I would guess that Heroes of Newarth comes with the libpng.so file. You could try appending the path to that libpng.so file (it would be in the directory where heroes of newarth is) to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but don't do it permanently (it shouldn't go in ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile).

Comment: The command ./hon-x86_64 can only be run when you are in the same directory as that file.

Comment: oh. Well I ran export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/c0ding/HoN/libs-x86_64/libpng12.so.0
 and got the same error. DId I use the command wrong?

Comment: Also got: "warning: The VAD has been replaced by a hack pending a complete rewrite
K2 - Fatal Error: PNG header and library versions do not match"